# Unable to get previous stats of app from itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

I upload a iphone app on 2013 in itunesconnect account, after the smooth usage of 2 years I need to transfer my app in another account of mine. So that i moved it from previos account to another account (Which is in use from 2012).
Now my issue is that i want to know about the stats of my app, is that how many downloads are there from 2013 - till now but after login i got stats report from Apil 2015 as date picker of app analytics get diable after April 2015.

Please help me how can i get the complete stats of my app.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Then what is the use of iTunesconnect tag and iTunesconnect analytics tag which is available as a tag while asking for question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's App Analytics was only introduced last year, so you won't get data before that. (Also only on iOS 8+ devices)

You can try to use the Catalog report feature and get the sales data out. Basic sales data (Unit) are available in the "Sales & Trends" section of iTunes Connect. There you can also choose a timeframe that suits your needs. (I just checked it, it's working for me)

[image]

If you want any usage data, it's not possible to get that via iTunes Connect.